# Windows Batch - Creating a tool that pings a list of IPs and outputs the three IPs with the lowest ms (time) to reach the server

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, network-programming, ping

I am trying to make a tool that pings a list of IPs and outputs the three IPs with the lowest ms (time) to reach the servers.

Input: -list of IPs seperated by spaces- such as 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2 1.1.1.3 etc

Output: -the three IPs with lowest ms- (in order of lowest ms on left to 3rd lowest ms on right) such as 1.1.2.2 1.2.3.3 1.4.4.4

I have this for the ping part so far:

```
@echo off
set ip=8.8.8.8
for /f "tokens=4 delims=(=" %%a IN ('ping %ip% -n 1 ^|find "Average = "') do echo Result is %%a
pause
```

This mini-code will output the ms ping from each server.

I need to find the ping of each server and compare them.

Can anyone help me with all this? I am sorry if I was not detailed enough and if I didn't show enough details or code.

Comment: I get why you guys downvote, but there are tons of people who don't even put any effort or code into their work, and they get over 100 hundred upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: IPs from http://etherealmind.com/what-is-the-best-ip-address-to-ping-to-test-my-internet-connection/
Set "IPlist=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 4.2.2.2 141.1.1.1"
For %%A in (%IPlist%) Do (
  Set IP=%%A
  for /f "tokens=6delims==, " %%B in (
    'ping %%A -n 1^|findstr Average'
  ) Do (
    Set PingRes=%%B
    Set /A Avg=100000+!PingRes:ms=!
    Set MS_!Avg!_!IP:.=!=!IP!
  )
)
Echo Show intermediate results
Set MS_1

Set Cnt=0 & Set "NewIPlist="
For /f "tokens=2,4 delims=_=" %%A in ('Set MS_1') Do (
  Set /A Cnt+=1
  if !Cnt! gtr 3 Goto :End
  Set NewIPlist=!NewIPlist! %%B
)
:End
Echo(
Set NewIPlist=%NewIPlist:~1%
Set NewIPlist
```

Try to understand what the batch does, ask if you have any questions.

Sample output

```
> Measure-IP.cmd
Show intermediate results
MS_100013_141111=141.1.1.1
MS_100013_20867220220=208.67.220.220
MS_100014_4222=4.2.2.2
MS_100027_20867222222=208.67.222.222
MS_100028_8888=8.8.8.8
MS_100032_8844=8.8.4.4

NewIPlist=141.1.1.1 208.67.220.220 4.2.2.2
```

Comment: Is there a way you can not have it echo: Show intermediate results
MS_100013_141111=141.1.1.1
MS_100013_20867220220=208.67.220.220
MS_100014_4222=4.2.2.2
MS_100027_20867222222=208.67.222.222
MS_100028_8888=8.8.8.8
MS_100032_8844=8.8.4.4

Comment: Of course, I inserted these lines intentionally to help understand what the batch does, it's quite easy to identify the 2 relevant lines. [SO] is a site for programmers searching and providing help. From your recent questions I see that all the commands should be familiar but I miss effort from your side to learn. So you shouldn't be astonished to get down voted.

Comment: I found a way to remove that echo part. Thanks for the information, I will try to put more effort when creating a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set the list of IP's
set "IPs=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 4.2.2.2 141.1.1.1"

rem Set the number of desired IP's in the output
set "num=3"

rem Initialize "MS" array with large numbers
for /L %%i in (1,1,%num%) do set "MS[%%i]=9999"

for %%a in (%IPs%) do (
   set "ip=%%a"
   for /F "tokens=6 delims== " %%b in ('ping %%a -n 1 ^| find "Average = "') do (
      set "ms=%%b" & set "ms=!ms:ms=!"
      REM ECHO %%a = !ms!

      rem Insert this ms and ip values in their right position in MS and IP arrays
      for /L %%i in (1,1,%num%) do if !ms! lss !MS[%%i]! (
         set /A t=MS[%%i], MS[%%i]=ms, ms=t
         set "t=!IP[%%i]!" & set "IP[%%i]=!ip!" & set "ip=!t!"
      )

  )
)

echo %IP[1]% (%MS[1]%), %IP[2]% (%MS[2]%), %IP[3]% (%MS[3]%)
```

Output example:

```
208.67.222.222 (42), 208.67.220.220 (44), 4.2.2.2 (47)
```